# Converting Entity to DTO along with child entities

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

Trying to convert an entity object to local object so i can use it for further transformations.

Here is the code that i am using to convert the entity object;

```
IEnumerable<SystemArea> result = (from sa in CurrentContext.systemarea                                 
                                 select new SystemArea
                                 {
                                     SystemAreaId = sa.SystemAreaId,
                                     SystemAreaCode = sa.SystemAreaCode,
                                     SystemAreaType = sa.SystemAreaType,
                                     SystemAreaDescription = sa.SystemAreaDescription,
                                     SystemAreaCreatedDate = sa.SystemAreaCreatedDate,
                                     SystemAreaUpdateDate = sa.SystemAreaUpdateDate,
                                     SystemAreaStatus = sa.SystemAreaStatus,
                                     Count = sa.systemareafunctionality.Count,
                                     SystemAreaFunctionality = sa.systemareafunctionality.Select(e => new SystemAreaFunctionality { SystemAreaCode =e.SystemAreaCode })
                                 }).ToList();
```

Here the count variable is to confirm whether there is any child data in it.

SystemAreaFunctionality is the child object that i am trying to convert here by using **SELECT** function but it is always blank collection. Rest data is getting assigned to parent object but the only thing missing here is the child table records. Where am i going wrong, please help!

Generated SQL :

```
SELECT
`Project3`.`C1`, 
`Project3`.`SystemAreaId`, 
`Project3`.`SystemAreaCode`, 
`Project3`.`SystemAreaType`, 
`Project3`.`SystemAreaDescription`, 
`Project3`.`SystemAreaCreatedDate`, 
`Project3`.`SystemAreaUpdateDate`, 
`Project3`.`SystemAreaStatus`, 
`Project3`.`C3` AS `C2`, 
`Project3`.`C2` AS `C3`, 
`Project3`.`SystemAreaCode1`
FROM (SELECT
`Project1`.`SystemAreaId`, 
`Project1`.`SystemAreaCode`, 
`Project1`.`SystemAreaType`, 
`Project1`.`SystemAreaDescription`, 
`Project1`.`SystemAreaCreatedDate`, 
`Project1`.`SystemAreaUpdateDate`, 
`Project1`.`SystemAreaStatus`, 
1 AS `C1`, 
`Project2`.`SystemAreaCode` AS `SystemAreaCode1`, 
`Project2`.`C1` AS `C2`, 
`Project1`.`C1` AS `C3`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent1`.`SystemAreaId`, 
`Extent1`.`SystemAreaCode`, 
`Extent1`.`SystemAreaType`, 
`Extent1`.`SystemAreaDescription`, 
`Extent1`.`SystemAreaCreatedDate`, 
`Extent1`.`SystemAreaUpdateDate`, 
`Extent1`.`SystemAreaStatus`, 
(SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `A1`
FROM `systemareafunctionality` AS `Extent2`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`SystemAreaCode` = `Extent2`.`SystemAreaCode`) AS `C1`
FROM `systemarea` AS `Extent1`) AS `Project1` LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
`Extent3`.`SystemAreaCode`, 
1 AS `C1`
FROM `systemareafunctionality` AS `Extent3`) AS `Project2` ON `Project1`.`SystemAreaCode` = `Project2`.`SystemAreaCode`) AS `Project3`
 ORDER BY 
`Project3`.`SystemAreaCode` ASC, 
`Project3`.`C2` ASC
```

JSON output:

> [{"SystemAreaId":1,"SystemAreaCode":"KIO","SystemAreaType":"KIOSK","SystemAreaDescription":"tasks
>   related to
>   receptionist","SystemAreaCreatedDate":"/Date(1543421018000)/","SystemAreaUpdateDate":"/Date(1543421018000)/","SystemAreaStatus":true,"SystemAreaFunctionality":[],"Count":1}]

PS : Please don't suggest automapper or extension methods. Thanks!

Comment: Is `sa.systemareafunctionality` an IQueryable?

Comment: no its ICollection

Comment: If it wasn't there you would bet an error.  Add ToList() : SystemAreaFunctionality = sa.systemareafunctionality.Select(e => new SystemAreaFunctionality { SystemAreaCode =e.SystemAreaCode }).ToList()

Comment: What EF is this (6 or Core)?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF 6+ not core

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL? e.g. replace `ToList()` with `ToString()` and evaluate in the Watch window. Also assuming the problem is that you are getting `Count` > 0, but `SystemAreaFunctionality ` empty, correct?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes count > 0, updated question with generated  sql

Comment: Hmm, very strange. You are doing nothing wrong and the SQL looks ok. May be some discrepancy between database and C#  ordering if `SystemAreaCode` is string (`varchar` / `char`)

Comment: @IvanStoev yes SystemAreaCode is string and the key.. the count shows > 0 and no error at all, feeling helpless here.

Comment: Yeah, looks like EF/data issue. Does "normal" eager loading work? e.g. `var result = CurrentContext.systemarea.Include(sa => sa.systemareafunctionality).ToList();`. I mean populating the `systemareafunctionality` with data?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes did as suggested in below answer, also _Include_ only takes string path parameter did not find any other overload.

Comment: `using System.Data.Entity;` will make it available for you (it's an extension method), but anyway. If it doesn't work, then definitely you have EF issue with your string data. Check the values in database for casing/padding differences. See, if  `ORDER BY AreaCode ASC` uses different rules from C# default string comparison, EF won't be able to materialize correctly the returned union data set. This is the only logical reason coming to my mind.

Comment: @IvanStoev Finally got SystemAreaFunctionality data loaded by EF, but EF will only load it if i ask for the child table of SystemAreaFunctionality. Anyways the string key was not the problem here, guess i have to sacrifice a few bits of memory to make this work.

Comment: @MattBurner It would be nice if you post self answer explaining what was the issue and how you resolved it, because it really sounded (and still sounds) weird.

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry for delayed answering, have posted what i experienced and answered accordingly. Please also feel free to correct me.

Comment: Have you tried an INCLUDE of the collection?

Comment: @Oswald yes i did, just like Omer had suggested in his answer.. EF by default should be able to include all data, *lazy load* primary goal is to provide data when asked for and that is exactly what my linq statement is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPINION :**

Took me two days to make MySQL(latest version) work with EF and trust me it was painstaking and on the contrary EF with MSSQL is so simple and easy to implement.

One thing i experienced is that Oracle is not interested in providing support for the free version of MySQL whatsoever, so they are being sloppy on the documentation of new version and are providing unstable .NET connectors.

**ACTUAL ANSWER :**

EF was behaving so weirdly, that it would only load the data in the child entity (SystemAreaFunctionality) only if i asked EF to load the child of the child entity (i.e. SystemAreaFunctionalityEmployeeRoleMapping which is child to SystemAreaFuncionality), which also means that i had to take unnecessary data.

So my link query looks like this :

```
var result = (from sa in CurrentContext.systemarea
                          select new SystemArea
                          {
                              SystemAreaId = sa.SystemAreaId,
                              SystemAreaType = sa.SystemAreaType,
                              Count = sa.systemareafunctionality.Count,
                              SystemAreaFunctionalities = sa.systemareafunctionality.Select(saf => new SystemAreaFunctionality
                              {
                                  SystemAreaId = saf.SystemAreaId,
                                  SystemAreaFunctionalityController = saf.SystemAreaFunctionalityController,
                                  SystemAreaFunctionalityAction = saf.SystemAreaFunctionalityAction,
                                  SystemAreaFunctionalityType = saf.SystemAreaFunctionalityType,
                                  SystemAreaFunctionalityEmployeeRoleMappings = saf.systemareafunctionalityemployeerolemapping.Select(saferm => new SystemAreaFunctionalityEmployeeRoleMapping
                                  {
                                      SystemAreaFunctionalityEmployeeRoleMappingId = saferm.SystemAreaFunctionalityEmployeeRoleMappingId,
                                      SystemAreaFunctionalityCreatedDate = saferm.SystemAreaFunctionalityCreatedDate
                                  })
                              })
                          }).ToList();
```

**ALTERNATIVELY :**

Tried using the same linq query (posted in OP) with different database this time with PostgreSQL plus npgsql connector and surprisingly EF gives me exactly what i want with out extra baggage. 
On top of that PostgreSQL gives better performance with EF than MySQL. So i presume that switching to PostgreSQL would be a better option.

***PS :*** *If you are deciding on open sources DBMS then please refer this before jumping in with MySQL :*

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emgJtr9tIME
- https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/40x3nx/which_orm_is_the_right_choice_for_mysql

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
CurrentContext.systemarea.Include('systemareafunctionality')
```

or

```
IEnumerable<SystemArea> result = (from sa in CurrentContext.systemarea    
                             join systemareafunctionality in CurrentContext.systemareafunctionality on sa.systemareafunctionalityID equals systemareafunctionality.ID
                             select new SystemArea
                             {
                                 SystemAreaId = sa.SystemAreaId,
                                 SystemAreaCode = sa.SystemAreaCode,
                                 SystemAreaType = sa.SystemAreaType,
                                 SystemAreaDescription = sa.SystemAreaDescription,
                                 SystemAreaCreatedDate = sa.SystemAreaCreatedDate,
                                 SystemAreaUpdateDate = sa.SystemAreaUpdateDate,
                                 SystemAreaStatus = SystemAreaStatus,
                                 Count = systemareafunctionality.Count,
                                 SystemAreaFunctionality = systemareafunctionality.Select(e => new SystemAreaFunctionality { SystemAreaCode =e.SystemAreaCode })
                             }).ToList();
```

or

```
IEnumerable<SystemArea> result = (from sa in CurrentContext.systemarea    
                         join systemareafunctionality in CurrentContext.systemareafunctionality on sa.systemareafunctionalityID equals systemareafunctionality.ID into item1 from subitem1 in item1.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                         select new SystemArea
                         {
                             SystemAreaId = sa.SystemAreaId,
                             SystemAreaCode = sa.SystemAreaCode,
                             SystemAreaType = sa.SystemAreaType,
                             SystemAreaDescription = sa.SystemAreaDescription,
                             SystemAreaCreatedDate = sa.SystemAreaCreatedDate,
                             SystemAreaUpdateDate = sa.SystemAreaUpdateDate,
                             SystemAreaStatus = SystemAreaStatus,
                             Count = systemareafunctionality.Count,
                             SystemAreaFunctionality = systemareafunctionality.Select(e => new SystemAreaFunctionality { SystemAreaCode =e.SystemAreaCode })
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think join made any difference here, because i tried join before making it a normal select query.

Comment: did you try left join like this: 
 join systemareafunctionality in CurrentContext.systemareafunctionality on sa.systemareafunctionalityID equals systemareafunctionality.ID into item1 from subitem1 in item1.DefaultIfEmpty()

Comment: yes i did, anyways it is a child table so ef context will have the data inside its parent

Comment: did you try to make LazyLoadingEnabled set true?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your `CurrentContext` is a `Dbcontext` with at least a table of `SystemAreas` and a table of `SystemAreaFunctionalities`.

It seems that every `SystemArea` has zero or more `SystemAreaFunctionalities`; every `SystemAreaFunctionality` belongs to exactly one `SystemArea`, a straightforward one-to-many relationship using a foreign key.

Note: it might be that you have a many-to-many relation, the answer will be similar

Alas you forgot to write your classes, so I'll give a shot:

```
class SystemArea
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every SystemArea has zero or more SystemAreaFunctionalities (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<SystemAreaFunctionality> SystemAreaFunctionalities {get; set;}
}

class SystemAreaFunctionality
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every SystemAreaFunctionality belongs to exactly one SystemArea, using foreign key
    public int SystemAreaId {get; set;}
    public virtual SystemArea SystemArea {get; set;}
}
```

> In entity framework the columns of your tables are represented by non-virtual properties, the virtual properties represent the relationships between the tables. (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

for completeness:

```
class CurrentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SystemArea> SystemAreas {get; set;}
    public DbSet<SystemAreaFunctionality> SystemAreaFunctionalities {get; set;}
}
```

If people want items with their sub-items, like `Schools` with their `Students`, `Customers` with their `Orders`, etc. people tend to perform a `(group)Join`. However, when using entity framework joins are seldom necessary. Ise the ICollections instead. Entity framework knows the relationships and knows which (group)join to perform.

Regularly I see people use `Include`, but if you do that, you'll select the complete object, which is not very efficient. Suppose you have a `SystemArea` with Id = 10, and 1000 `SystemAreaFunctionalities`, you know that every `SystemAreaFunctionality` has a foreign key `SystemAreaId` with a value 10. Instead of sending this value only once as primary key of `SystemArea`, `Include` will also select all 1000 foreign keys with this value 10. What a waste of processing power!

> When querying data, always use Select and select only the properties you actually plan to use. Only use Include if you plan to Update the included object.

You wrote:

> SystemAreaFunctionality is the child object that i am trying to convert here...

It is not clear what you really want. Do you want a collection of all used SystemAreaCodes? Or do you really want a collection of new SystemAreaFunctionalities where only one field is filled: SystemAreaCode? Because of you use of singular property name, it seems you don't want a collection but only one item.

```
var result = currentContext.SystemAreas.Select(systemArea => new
{
     Id = systemArea.Id,
     Code = systemArea.Code,
     ...

     // if you want a collection of SystemAreaFunctionalities
     // where every SystemAreaFunctionality is filled with only SysemAreaCode
     // do the following:
     SystemAreaFunctionalities = systemArea.SystemAreaFunctionalities
          .Select(systemAreaFunctionality => new SystemAreFunctionality
          {
               SystemAreaCode = systemAreaFunctionality.SystemAreaCode,
          })
          .ToList(),   // DON'T FORGET THIS, OR YOU WON'T GET RESULTS!
    })
    .ToList()
}
```

**I think the cause of your empty SystemAreaFunctionalities is because you forgot to do ToList().**

Because you used ToList(), you automatically have the Count of the selected SystemAreaFunctionalities. There is no need to select this Count separately.

> One of the slower parts of database queries is the transport of the selected data from the database management system to your local process. It is good practice to only select data you actually plan to use

You query is not very efficient because you select complete SystemAreaFunctionalities and  fill only the SystemAreaCode. All other fields will be filled by default values. Apart from the slower query, you also give your callers the impression that they get properly filled SystemAreaFunctionalities. An improved version would be:

```
var result = currentContext.SystemAreas.Select(systemArea => new
{
     // select only the properties you actually plan to use
     Id = systemArea.Id,
     Code = systemArea.Code,
     ...


     // if you only need the SystemAreaCodes, select only that property
     SystemAreaCodes = systemArea.SystemAreaFunctionalities
          .Select(systemAreaFunctionality => systemAreaFunctionality.SystemAreaCode)
          .ToList(),
    })
    .ToList()
};
```

Of courds, if you need mrre than only the SystemAreaCodes, but several SystemAreaFunctionalities, go ahead, select them:

```
...
SystemAreaFunctionalities = systemArea.SystemAreaFunctionalities
    .Select(systemAreaFunctionality => new
    {
        // again: select only the properties you plan to use!
        Id = systemAreaFunctionality.Id
        SystemAreaCode = systemAreaFunctionality.SystemAreaCode,
     })
```

Comment: Tried what you mentioned did not yield anything, _SystemArea_ has one to many relationship only with _SystemAreaFunctionality_ also my query is perfect because i need all the information available, i just did not add it in the code posted in question.

Answer (score 0):

An include should do the trick for you like so:

```
    IEnumerable<SystemArea> result = (from sa in CurrentContext.systemarea.Include("systemareafunctionality")                                 
                             select new SystemArea
                             {
                                 SystemAreaId = sa.SystemAreaId,
                                 SystemAreaCode = sa.SystemAreaCode,
                                 SystemAreaType = sa.SystemAreaType,
                                 SystemAreaDescription = sa.SystemAreaDescription,
                                 SystemAreaCreatedDate = sa.SystemAreaCreatedDate,
                                 SystemAreaUpdateDate = sa.SystemAreaUpdateDate,
                                 SystemAreaStatus = sa.SystemAreaStatus,
                                 Count = sa.systemareafunctionality.Count,
                                 SystemAreaFunctionality = sa.systemareafunctionality.Select(e => new SystemAreaFunctionality { SystemAreaCode =e.SystemAreaCode })
                             }).ToList();
```